# Python Stacked Barchart from Counter using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, counter, bar-chart

I have a large csv file. This file is read and a `Counter` is returned every predefined amount of lines. As an Example:

`counter = [Counter({(0, 1): 9, (1, 2): 8}), Counter({(1, 2): 99, (0, 1): 99}), Counter({(1, 2): 256, (0, 1): 189}), Counter({(1, 5): 473, (0, 1): 301})]`

This is the script i used.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
from collections import Counter
counter = [Counter({(0, 1): 9, (1, 2): 8}), Counter({(1, 2): 99, (0, 1): 99}), Counter({(1, 2): 256, (0, 1): 189}), Counter({(1, 5): 473, (0, 1): 301})]

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

N = len(counter)
ind = numpy.arange(N)

j = 0
while j in range(0, len(counter)):
    a, i = 0, 0
    frequencies = counter[j].values()
    names = counter[j].keys()
    while i in range(0, len(frequencies)):
        if i == 0:
            ax1.bar(ind, frequencies[i], label=names[i], width=0.25)
            a = frequencies[i]
        else:
            ax1.bar(ind, frequencies[i], label=names[i], width=0.25, bottom=a)
            a += frequencies[i]
        i += 1
    j += 1
labels = ["%s to %s" % (200, 202)]
ax1.set_xticks(numpy.arange(N))
ax1.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax1.set_ylabel("Frequency")
ax1.set_xlabel("Material Contact")
ax1.legend()

plt. show()
```

**However, it returns as error message:**

> ValueError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 4 or
>   scalar

Which i believe is related to the `ind` array.

*To overcome this, i changed the `ind` to `ind[j]` in the if statement. However, the end result is a lot of bars with a lot of colours. The colours do not relate to their respective bins, as expected.*

```
ax1.bar(ind[j], frequencies[i], label=names[i], width=0.25)
```

**Obtained Results:**
[image: Obtained Results]

**Expected Results:**
[image: Expected Results]

Update:
A possible solution could be to build an array from the Counter. However, that defies the concept of the Counter being implemented in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only answer was to reevaluate and restructure the data

```
series = {}
for key in {key for keys in counter for key in keys}:
    series[key] = [(0 if key not in item else item[key]) for item in counter]
```

Credits to the help received from zivoni on [python-forum](https://python-forum.io/)